# react redux merge state with given array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Lets say I have a reducer which is like :

```
const initialState = [
  {
    accessToken: null,
    isLoggedIn: false,
  }
]

export default function my_reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGIN:
        return state.merge(user: action) ---> how to handle this
```

and the output should be like:

```
[
      {
        accessToken: null,
        isLoggedIn: false,
        user: {
            name: 'some name',
            email: 'some email'
      }
    ]
```

In action I am getting a array which I am providing by doing `JSON.stringify(response)`

previous data should not be changed and new data should be updated

Answer (score 4):

## The ES6 Way

To create a new object with the state in ES6 we can use the spread operator. Like this

```
...
case ActionType.SUCCESS_GET_DATA : {
    let newState = { ...state, [action.uniqueKey]: action.payload };
    return state.merge(newState);
}
...
```

I did the `uniqueKey` part as a variable because you will want a unique name for your state.

IMO this syntax is much easier to understand than the `Object.assign`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) function:

```
var state = {
    accessToken: null,
    isLoggedIn: false,
};

var user = {
    name: 'some name',
    email: 'some email'
};

var newState = Object.assign({}, state, {user});

console.log(newState);
```

Comment: newState is mutated if you assign new property to state at later stage. Hence first to assign should be an empty object literal.

Answer (score 1):

First I see that your state is actually an array, but I think you would need an object right?

So it would be:

```
const initialState = {
    accessToken: null,
    isLoggedIn: false,
}
```

(requires Babel) So with spread operator you can:

```
return {
    ...initialState,
  user: {
    name: '...',
    surname: '...'
  }
};
```

Or if you do not transpile via Babel alike:

```
return Object.assign({}, initialState, {
    user: {
    name: '...',
    surname: '...'
  }
});
```

Comment: gives `invalid token on ...initialState`

Comment: @gamer you need to use Babel  to use the spread operator ...
So if you do not use it  check the Object.assign example.
More about babel at http://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/

Comment: I used `Object.assign` method but its returning me object.. while expecting array.. I have changed the state to `object` but also giving me same error...

Answer (score 0):

Using ES6 spread syntax

```
...
case 'ACTION_TYPE_A': {
return { ...state, action.key: action.value };
}
...
```

This will return the merged state by updating the 'key' if it exists in the original state.

Answer (score 0):

```
Everything according to new Es6 format : )
```

A total addToDo reducer function where the data is appended to the previous state. And you get the output of a new state data : )

```
export const addToDo = (state, action) => {
const { name, email, phone, image,key } = action;
  var data = [...state.data];
  var newData = {
     name: name, email: email, phone: phone, image: image,key:key 
  }
   data.push(newData)

return(
state.merge({
  data : data
})

)};
```

Happy coding.